# Redis data is getting overridden by Docker Entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need a redis container start with some predefined configurations which my application will use.

I found a solution by adding data (using CMD) while reading docker file.

Docker file :-

```
FROM redis:latest
COPY my-data.redis /my-dir/
COPY my-redis.sh /my-dir/
CMD ["sh", "/my-dir/my-redis.sh"]
```

my-redis.sh :-

```
redis-server --daemonize yes && sleep 1 
redis-cli < /my-dir/my-data.redis 
redis-cli save 
redis-cli shutdown 
redis-server
```

my-data.redis :-

```
SET key1 val1
SET key2 val2
```

docker-compose :-

```
redis:
    image: my-redis:latest
    networks:
      - back-tier
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    #command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
    volumes:
    - ./data/redis-data:/data
    restart: always
```

My predefined data is getting populated to the redis container but when i am modifiying the data, its getting overridden when the container is getting restart.

PS :- I have mapped redis-data outside but at the time of restart its getting modified.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to re-initialize Redis every time the container starts, then you need to include logic in your startup script to prevent that behavior. Something as simple as:

```
if ! [ -f /etc/redis-was-configured ]; then
  redis-server --daemonize yes && sleep 1 
  redis-cli < /my-dir/my-data.redis 
  redis-cli save 
  redis-cli shutdown 
  touch /etc/redis-was-configured
fi

redis-server
```

This would create a flag file after configuring Redis, and if that file exists when the container starts it causes it to skip over the initial data load.

Rather than relying on a flag file, you could instead run a Redis query to check if the expected data is available, but in general what I've presented here is sufficient (and is a fairly common solution to this sort of issue).